# Embed GIF into dll (Firebreath)

Tags: visual-c++, resources, firebreath

I'm trying to embed a GIF into my plugin but I'm failing to get the resource; this is what I'm doing:

```
HMODULE hModule = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
HRSRC hResInfo = FindResource(hModule, MAKEINTRESOURCE(201), L"GIF");
```

That is into the OnPluginReady() event, this is the **firebreathWin.rc**:

```
IDB_BITMAP1             GIF                     "C:/loader.gif"
```

And this into the **resource.h**:

```
#define IDB_BITMAP1                     201
```

The exact same procedure, is working on a console application; but not in my firebreath project.

Using, Visual C++ 2010.

Comment: `HMODULE hModule;
GetModuleHandleEx(GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_UNCHANGED_REFCOUNT, L"myDll.dll", &hModule);
HRSRC hResInfo = FindResource(hModule, MAKEINTRESOURCE(201), L"GIF");` I've solved the problem that way in case someone needs a solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at [dllmain.cpp](https://github.com/firebreath/FireBreath/blob/master/src/PluginAuto/Win/dllmain.cpp) you'll see that there is a global HINSTANCE gInstance that you can use:

```
extern HINSTANCE gInstance;
HRSRC hRes = FindResource(gInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(201), L"GIF");
```

You can also [get the full path and filename of your dll](http://www.firebreath.org/display/documentation/Tips+and+Tricks#TipsandTricks-GettingthepathandfilenameofthepluginDLLsoordylib) pretty easily from FireBreath if you want to use the other method so that you aren't depending on your filename never changing.